# Python - If/Elif statement (loops)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Can someone tell me why I'm getting 4 as the outcome? Should 3 be printing instead because the code is satisfied in the If section.

```
a = 15

if a&5  == 0:
    print('3')
elif a% 5 == 0:
    print('4')

else:
    print('5')
```

Comment: Because `15&5` will evaluate to `5` and `5` never equals to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

& is bitwise AND and works like this:

15 & 5

```
  1111
& 0101
------
  0101 != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the bits of 15 with the bits of 5, resulting in the ones they have in common.

```
1111 & 101 => 101
```

so the result is 5, not 0.

Answer (score 3):

The **"&"** operator is a **Bitwise AND** so in your code it is like:

```
1111 & 0101 = 0101
```

That means

```
15 and 5 = 5
```

So the first condition can not be true and you'll get `4` in output because the reminder of `15/5` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check LSB then you should do "and" with 1 and check the result if it's 1 then LSB is 0 else LSB is 1